# Как настроить Микроразметку (shema.org.ua) в Joomla?

Tags: joomla

Joomla! 3.6.0
Как реализовать валидную микроразметку на сайте и верно ввести в индекс Google.
например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Joomla 3 по дефолту уже реализованна поддержка микроразметки для статей, категорий, "хлебной крошки" (breadcrumb). Если этого недостаточно можно воспользоватся плагином https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/google-structured-data-markup

Comment: да оно там есть но подключения самой микроразметки по дефолту нету и вроде никогда небыло( (breadcrumb) там есть но он не индексируется так как shema.org не подключена

Comment: Подключений не надо, если сайт на Joomla 3 всё должно работать , проверьте  ссылки сайта через инструмент  https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/
попробуйте протестировать несколько различных страниц. как дополнительный вариант можете воспользоватся плагином для  'идеальной' получения микроразметки

Comment: Да плагин (бесплатная версия) работает только запустил в индекс пока из 169 ссилок только 3 изменилось (хлебные крошки заработали)

Comment: нужно время для индексации, можно через Google Web Master tools отправить ссылки для новой индексации + надо прочитать документацию к плагину и настроить если что то не так, а в остальном всё будет работать! :)

Comment: Ну спасибо )) вродь разобрался запустил на индекс буду ждать ))

Comment: Всегда рад помочь )) не забудь закрыть тему..

Comment: Да закрою отмечу все как надо только как проиндексирует ) думаю вечерком должно быть уже все